# RVM Installation Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I'm having some issues regarding the installation of RVM. I'm working with a freshly clean-installed mac, so previous folders and that sort of thing shouldn't be an issue. The steps I've taken so far are as follows:

1. Downloaded XCode Command Line Tools
2. Installed Homebrew
3. Verified I had Git installed
4. Used Homebrew to install gpg
5. Installed the gpg key thing
6. Used the `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` command to try to install RVM, and was met with this error:

   > df: /Users/rohan/.rvm: No such file or directory

I assumed that the command in number 6 automatically created the .rvm folder, so I'm a little unsure of how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue and now it works! You did nothing wrong. It's something wrong with the RVM website. Try to run the same command again and you will see everything works now!

Comment: OMG YES! It works! Thank you so much for letting me know I was on the verge of chucking my laptop out the window

Answer (score 0):

You can do these steps as below:

1. gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
2. \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

for more informations, you can check at official document:
http://rvm.io/

**update**: You can try to do this command

`curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -`

then run `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` again

Comment: So I've tried these steps, and unfortunately gotten the same output again: df: /Users/rohan/.rvm: No such file or directory

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Still getting the same error message as above /:. Really not sure where anything could have gone wrong.